Strange behavior of Blazor Authorization template
I can't get a component to be disabled using policy

Create an empty BlazorServer project with the WindowsAuthenticate authorization template.
Add a default policy that denies everything.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAssertion(x=>false).Build();
});


Add the AllowAnonumus attribute to the _host page. If you don’t add it, there will be no access to the site at all, it will return 403

@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]


Make sure that the template has one  component that requires authorization.

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

Now run the project, and at first you won’t see the login.
But if you quickly click on the NavBar you will see it. Explain how the code gets into <Authorized> tags

I found a temporary solution in the form of using asynchronous overload.
I don't know why that's how it works...
options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAssertion(x => new Task<bool>(() => false)).Build();

And it doesn't work like this:
options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAssertion(async x => false).Build();

My brain is broken.
Perhaps this is how the thread race works and you will generally have a different way.
